# How to use Apaches RedirectMatch to force non www version of domain

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I've only just discovered Apaches `Redirect` method as an alternative to using a .htaccess file in order to force a non www version of my domain.

The problem is I need to ensure any inner pages redirect to the non www version properly as at the moment the simple `Redirect / http://domainname.co.uk` will only effectively deal with my homepage. How can I set up a rule that will deal with any inner pages as well?

Additionally is this better or worse than just using my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of keeping it out of `.htaccess` files is it becomes a bit more maintainable and you don't have these files everywhere.

However something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Will redirect non www to www for any page and for the reverse (www to non-www) it should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Both directions have been added